# Customize order of y-axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run the code order of y-axis label is changed alphabetically,  but I want to keep it as like as my  `coef` column of `new.table` dataset. Here is my code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(data.table)
    

coef<-c("<=40 years", "41-55 years", "56+ years", "Underweight", "Normal", 
"Overweight", "Obese", "Uncontrolled", "Control", "Uncontrolled", "Control", 
"< 5 years", "5-10 years", ">= 10 years", "Adherence", "Non-adherence")
or<-c(1,0.98, 1.16, 1.68, 1, 0.59, 0.71, 2.57, 1, 1.1, 1, 1, 2.03, 9.51, 1, 1.82)
ci_lb<-c(1, 0.41, 0.47, 0.25, 1, 0.33, 0.34, 1.3, 1, 0.63, 1, 1, 0.81, 3.85, 1, 1.07)
ci_ub<-c(1, 2.35, 2.87, 11.22, 1, 1.03, 1.48, 5.08, 1, 1.92, 1, 1, 5.09, 23.46, 1, 3.1)
term<-c("Age", "Age", "Age", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "FBS", "FBS", "SBP", "SBP", "Duration", "Duration", "Duration", "Drug", "Drug")
is.reference<-rep(TRUE,16)

new.table<-data.frame(coef, or, ci_lb, ci_ub, term, is.reference)

p <- ggplot(new.table,
       aes(x = or, xmin = ci_lb, xmax = ci_ub,
           y = coef, color = term)) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,25))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 18) +
  facet_grid(term~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")+
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Covnert `new.table$coef` to factor class. `new.table$coef <- factor(new.table$coef, levels = new.table$coef)`

Comment: @zx8754 The proposal to work with factor does not work, as levels are not unique e.g. "Uncontrolled" and "Control".

Comment: @KoenV see my answer, that is what I had in mind, just didn't have time to post as answer, looks like it works.

Answer (score 2):

To extend my comment a bit, we need to set factor order on *coef* and on *term*, then reverse y axis:

```
# factor
new.table$coef <- factor(new.table$coef, levels = unique(new.table$coef))
new.table$term <- factor(new.table$term, levels = unique(new.table$term))

ggplot(new.table,
            aes(x = or, xmin = ci_lb, xmax = ci_ub,
                y = coef, color = term)) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,25))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 18) +
  facet_grid(term~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")+
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  # flip y-axis
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image]